# Spring boot validation constraint call programmatically

Tags: spring-boot, validation, hibernate-validator

I am trying to call a custom validation constraint programmatically, but something isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

MyConstraint.java

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = MyValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD,ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyConstraint {
    ...
}
```

MyValidator.java

```
@Component
public class MyValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MyConstraint, MyVO> {
    ...
}
```

I tried the below options to call validation constraint manually but not working.

MyClass.java

```
@Autowired
private SpringValidatorAdapter validator;

@Component
@Validated
public class MyClass {
    // ========= Option 1
    private String validate(final @MyConstraint MyVO vo) {
       return "success";
    }

    // ========= Option 2
    private BindingResult validate(final MyVO vo) {
        DataBinder binder = new DataBinder(vo);
        binder.setValidator(validator);
        binder.validate();
        return binder.getBindingResult();
    }
}
```

But validation constraint is working in controller-

MyController.java

```
@ApiOperation
@PostMapping(value = "/v1/validate")
ResponseEntity validate(@Valid @MyConstraint @RequestBody MyVO vo) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body("{\"msg\":\"Successfully Validated\"}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `@MyConstraint` annotaion in your `MyVO.class` as follows.

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@MyConstraint( message = "your error message")
public class MyVO
{ }
```

Also add `@Validated` in your method signature in your `MyClass.java`

```
private String validate(@Validated MyVO vo) {}
```